# AppAuth, Redirect URI, Stackexchange, Instagram API

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, instagram-api, stackexchange-api, appauth

I want to make OAuth2 authorization.

I use : implementation ["net.openid:appauth:0.7.0"](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android)

I have studied many examples (Google Codelabs, AppAuth etc).

I also studied [RFC 8252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252).

I wanted to apply this to [Stackexchange](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) and [Instagram OAuth API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

I understood only one thing: custom REDIRECT_URI like "com.example.auth:/oauth2callback" it does not work anymore for SE and Instagram.

I tried different schemes with the same negative result.

**My problem is that RedirectUriReceiverActivity does not start.**

**Can anyone specify the correct Redirect URI settings (for the Android app and AppAuth lib) for the SE or the Insta OAuth API ?**

Manifest (I've tried many options here)

```
<activity android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
tools:node="replace">
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data android:scheme="com.example.auth"
                data android:scheme="https"
                 android:host="stackexchange.com"
                 android:path="/oauth/login_success"/>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

MainActivity (I tried many options for REDIRECT_URI)

```
private static final String AUTH_ENDPOINT = "https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog";
    private static final String TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token";
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "123";
    //private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "com.example.auth:/oauth2callback";
    //private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success"; //  com.example.auth://oauth/login_success
    private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "com.example.auth://oauth/login_success";
    private static final String SCOPES_AUTH = "no_expiry read_inbox";

// Authorization service configuration
            AuthorizationServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration = new AuthorizationServiceConfiguration(
                    Uri.parse(AUTH_ENDPOINT) /* auth endpoint  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1 */,
                    Uri.parse(TOKEN_ENDPOINT) /* token endpoint https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.2 */,
                    null /* (optional) registration endpoint https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7591#section-3 */
            );
// Obtaining an authorization code
            Uri redirectUri = Uri.parse(REDIRECT_URI);
            AuthorizationRequest.Builder builder = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
                    serviceConfiguration,
                    CLIENT_ID,
                    ResponseTypeValues.CODE, // the response_type value: we want a code
                    redirectUri
            );
            builder.setScopes(SCOPES_AUTH);
            AuthorizationRequest request = builder.build();

            Context context = view.getContext();

            // do Authorization
            AuthorizationService authorizationService = new AuthorizationService(context);

            Intent postAuthorizationIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            postAuthorizationIntent.setAction(HANDLE_AUTHORIZATION_RESPONSE);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, request.hashCode(), postAuthorizationIntent, 0);
authorizationService.performAuthorizationRequest(request, pendingIntent);
```